# Flutter Nested Routing Issue

Tags: flutter, routes, nested, navigation

I am trying to implement Nested routing in Flutter.

Here is a sample from my project tree.

[image]

When I am on the `Page` widget and try to head back to the `LandingPage` widget using the backbutton, the app closes.

can someone help me with that

Here is a code sample:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Code Sample for Navigator',
      // MaterialApp contains our top-level Navigator
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => Home(),
        '/app': (BuildContext context) => App(),
      },
    );
  }
}



class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      ..
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context)=> Navigator(
          initialRoute: 'LandingPage',

          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
            WidgetBuilder builder;
            switch (settings.name) {
              case 'LandingPage':
                builder = (BuildContext _) => LandingPage();
                break;
              case 'Page':
                builder = (BuildContext _) => Page();
                break;
              default:
                throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
            }
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
          },

        ); 
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can see what you are doing wrong

Comment: I think its related to this issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14083

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by using `Navigator.maybePop()` with `WillPopScope()` properly.

According to Flutter's [`maybePop()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/maybePop.html), it is used instead of `pop()` to handle user's tap on the device's backbutton.

by reversing it's behavior when in the nested navigator, pressing the backbutton won't pop the root navigator, but pop only the nested navigator.

for example:

```dart
class SecondNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondNavigator({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SecondNavigatorState createState() => _SecondNavigatorState();
}

class _SecondNavigatorState extends State<SecondNavigator> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Navigator(
                key: navigatorKey,
                ...
              ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        final NavigatorState navigator = navigatorKey.currentState;
        return !await navigator.maybePop();        
      },
    );
  }
}
```

A full example was provided [here](https://github.com/rmtmckenzie/flutter_nested_navigators)

make sure to check out flutter's docs of [`willpop()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/willPop.html) to better understand `maypop()`

Answer (score 0):

Route to pages like this as standard way

```
    initialRoute: "/screen1",
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/screen1': (BuildContext context) =>  Screen1(),
      '/screen2': (BuildContext context) =>  Screen2(),
      '/screen3': (BuildContext context) =>  Screen3(),
      '/screen4': (BuildContext context) =>  Screen4()
    },
    onUnknownRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
      return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
            Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Not Found'))),
      );
    },
  )
);
```

Comment: I need to add MultiProvider that starts only when screen1 is active. 
Also, screen1 is going to have sub-screens that depends on the providers inside MultiProvider 

so it is going to be something like this:
MultiProvider > screen1 > screen1.A > screen1.A.B

Comment: Make it easy by setting `MultiProvider` as parent of `MaterialApp` widget